# WIFEXITED,WEXITSTATUS and WNOHANGS in linux

Tags: c, linux

```
int main()
{
  pid_t pid;
  int status,exit_status;
  if((pid = fork()) < 0)
{
 perror("error at fork\n");
 exit(0);
}
 if(pid == 0)
{
  printf("child process %d is sleeping...\n",getpid());
  sleep(5);
  exit(0);
}
 while (waitpid(pid,&status,0) > 0)
{
 printf("parent process is waiting ...\n");
 sleep(1);
}


 if(WIFEXITED(status))
{
 exit_status = WEXITSTATUS(status);
 printf("exit status from %d is %d\n",pid,exit_status);
}
 exit(0);
}
```

I am a bit not clear with the WIFEXITED,WEXITSTATUS and WNOHANGS. First i want to know the status variable,is that the status variable directly obtain from child process or parent process ? 
i had been read from online resource , WIFEXITED will evaluate to non-zero if the child process terminate normally and WEXITSTATUS will evaluate to the child exit node if the WEXITED is non-zero. Can i know where we get the WEXITED and how they work together base on my sample program. Besides, i also  not idea how WNOHANGS syntax function